# Why do I keep receiving ModuleNotFound error with pydot, despite having installed it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror, modulenotfounderror, pydot

I've installed pydot and checked to make sure of this several times. However, when I attempt to import it in a Juptyer notebook file, I keep receiving a Module Not Found error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydot'
```

When I run pip3 show pydot, I get the following response:

```
Name: pydot
Version: 1.4.2
Summary: Python interface to Graphviz's Dot
Home-page: https://github.com/pydot/pydot
Author: Ero Carrera
Author-email: ero.carrera@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /Users/parkertemple/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: pyparsing
Required-by:
```

After, when I run

```
 python3 myscript.py
```

I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/(my user account)/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm relatively new to the command line and am struggling a bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using mac os.
Thank you so much!

Comment: What's the content of your `myscript.py`?

Comment: How would I find this? I've looked around the internet and can't seem to follow much.. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon to have these problems when starting out.
*Usually* this problem relates to Python3 not understanding where the pip directory is making its installations.

Two paths you can consider in fixing this issue:

1. For Python 3.7 (try replacing it with your python3 version):

   `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages"`
2. Use a **Python virtual environment**. This is like making a specific python & pip installation. It's particularly useful because it isolates the modules that your project needs, making it more lightweight, shareable, etc. This will take a little more time to set up; but it can be very important to understand why virtual environments are beneficial to your project.